# How can I add custom code to the header

Tags: joomla, custom-code

How can I add the following line to the header, in a  component?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if it will work with any text, but you could try:

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag('<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->');
```

I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: Actually your solution works http://docs.joomla.org/JDocumentHTML/addCustomTag I didn't know that we can use addCustomTag. Thumb up :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
<?php
    $document = &JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addScript( '/js/excanvas.min.js' );
?>
```

I am searching for how to add the conditional statement though ...

**UPDATE**

Checking if the user agent is IE

```
<?php
    $document = &JFactory::getDocument();

    //Is it Internet Explorer?
    ereg('MSIE ([0-9]\.[0-9])',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],$reg);

    if(isset($reg[1])) {
        //Yes, it is Internet Explorer
        $document->addScript( '/js/excanvas.min.js' );
    }
?>
```